# Find on a model that's set as hasAndBelongsToMany

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I'm creating a clothing directory website with CakePHP. I have two models: `Store` and `Brand`. `Brand` is set up as a `hasAndBelongsToMany`, as a store can have many brands associated with it, but obviously a brand can apply to numerous stores.

I have my `StoresController` fetching stores as it should, but what I'm having trouble with is fetching a list of brands in my `BrandsController`. If I set my `Brand` model to have a `hasAndBelongsToMany` relationship with my `Store` model, can I no longer do something like `$this->Brand->find('all')`? When I do I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method Brand::find() in /[path]/app/controllers/brands_controller.php on line 8

Here are my model definitions:

```
class Brand {    
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Store' => array(
            'className' => 'Store',
            'joinTable' => 'brands_stores',
            'foreignKey' => 'brand_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'store_id',
            'unique' => true
        )
    );
}
```

And my `Store` model:

```
class Store extends AppModel {
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Reviews' => array(
            'className' => 'StoreReview',
            'foreignKey' => 'store_id',
            'conditions' => array(
                'approved' => 1
            ),
            'order' => 'created DESC'
        )
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Class Brand must extend AppModel, which you seem to have forgotten

Answer (score 2):

class Brand extends AppModel {